# Javascript understanding promises

Tags: javascript

I've been using async with NodeJS, but I'm trying to understand the basic of promises in JavaScript and I'm having issues with it.

I created the code below for testing.

```js
function first() {
  // Simulate a code delay
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(1);
    }, 500);
  });
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

first().then(second());
```

It should print '1' first, but it is printing '2' in the console first. Why is it happening?

Thanks

Comment: You never execute `resolve()`. You're supposed to execute `resolve()` inside your asynchronous function... in this case the function you pass to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

`first().then(second())` invokes `second()` *immediately* and passes its *return value* as the argument to `then`. You want to pass in **the function itself**, not its return value:

`first().then(second); // no parens on second`

---

And you're never resolving the first promise:

```js
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(1);
      resolve(); // <--  without this the promise is never resolved
    }, 500);
  }
);
```

---

With those issues addressed it works as you'd intended:

```js
function first() {
  // Simulate a code delay
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(1);
      resolve(); // <--  without this the promise is never resolved
    }, 500);
  });
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

first().then(second);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a 2 problems in your code :

1. Your function first() returns a promise, but it isn't a promise in itself, so you cannot use the .then attribute on it.
2. You're not resolving anything in your 1st promise, you're just console.logging something, which is not something you can "wait" for.

What you're looking for is more something like this :

```
let first = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout( function() {
    console.log("1");
    resolve(true); //you return your response, for example a boolean
  }, 500) 
}) 

function second(){
    console.log("2");
}

first.then(response => {
    //this is usually where you do something with the response
    second();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Async Await

> (as ray write) In `new Promise()` You must return `resolve()` or `reject()`

You can also use await:

```js
function first() {
  return new Promise(res => {
      console.log(1);
      return setTimeout(res, 500);
  })
}

function second() {
  console.log(2);
}

(async () => {
  await first();
  second();
})();
```